# SelectedIndexChanged is not Fired

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

Suppose that `Combobox` contol has two items - `A` and `B`, then user selects the `B` item. Then user selects `B` item again; In this case the `SelectedIndexChanged` is not fired by default, but my problem is that I need `SelectedIndexChanged` should be fired even when user selects the previous item again. How can I do this?

Comment: In this case `SelectedIndex` wasn't change. This is proper behaviour of control.

Comment: But why? you already picked up the same value.. and If there's a logic behind the SelectedIndexChanged it's already fired.

Comment: May be you can use DropDownClosed event

Comment: because there is no change happend. but if you want to track user action, its better to use DropDownClosed event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `DropDownClosed` event in addition of `SelectedIndexChanged` (just bind the events to the same method)

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behaviour of the control. But if you want this behaviour, you can achieve it in two ways.
1. you can set combobox.selectedIndex property to null everytime SelectedIndexChanged event gets fired.

```
void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // your code

     this.comboBox1.SelectedIndex = null;
}
```

or, 2. you can add another event handler for DropDownClosed event of combobox.